# Error "variable lengths differ" when assigning weights parameter in caret (R)

Tags: r, r-caret

I want to apply weighted observation in caret using the code below:

```
model_weights <- ifelse(train$y == 0,
                        (1/table(train$y)[1]) * 0.5,
                        (1/table(train$y)[2]) * 0.5)

xgbT <- train(x = as.matrix(train[,-21]), y = make.names(as.factor(train$y)), 
              method = "xgbTree", 
              trControl = cctrl1,
              metric = "MCC",
              maximize = TRUE,
              weights = model_weights,
              preProc = c("center", "scale"),
              tuneGrid = expand.grid(nrounds = c(150), #number of trees
                                    max_depth = c(7), #max tree depth
                                    eta = c(0.03), #learning rate
                                    gamma = c(0.3), #min split loss
                                    colsample_bytree = c(0.7),
                                    min_child_weight = c(10, 1, 5), #min number of instances in the leaf
                                    subsample = c(0.6)), #subsample ratio of the training instance
              early_stop_round = c(3), #if no improvements over specified rounds
              objective = c("binary:logistic"),
              silent = 0)
```

However, it gives me this error: `Error in model.frame.default(formula = .outcome ~ ., data = dat, weights = wts) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)')`

Though I have checked that their lengths are the same with code below:

```
> table(model_weights)
model_weights
0.0000277654375832963  0.000231481481481481 
                18008                  2160 
> table(train$y)

    0     1 
18008  2160
```

Any idea how to fix this?

NOTE: I can run the `train` function without `weights` parameter.

Comment: @missuse Yes, I checked it here: https://topepo.github.io/caret/train-models-by-tag.html#Accepts_Case_Weights

Comment: Which one? Please share the link

Comment: Sorry, morning... I assumed you linked it: [Here](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/RegressionTests/Code/xgbTree.R) it is - `test_class_cv_form_weight` example

Comment: When I run on `topepo's code` your `model_weights` I still get a result. It must be something in your data. Perhaps try to reduce the data to a smaller sample which can reproduce the problem and provide it with `dput` or as a download link.

Comment: Doesnt work also

Comment: Try using `weights = model_weights/max(model_weights)` If I do not provide that I get an output but the model is nonsense.

Comment: @missuse Fix the problem, I apply resampling in the trainControl which produces the error.

Answer (score 1):

After further debugging, I found the problem is because I apply `sampling` in the `cctrl1`. Thus, the length of `weights` differ, since I generate it before they apply re-sampling.

So, you can fix this by simply removing `sampling` from your `trControl`. If you still want to apply re-sampling, then you have to re-sample the data before running below code:

```
model_weights <- ifelse(train$y == 0,
                    (1/table(train$y)[1]) * 0.5,
                    (1/table(train$y)[2]) * 0.5)
```

Comment: Does the model obtained with such weights make sense? I found that one of the weights needs to be 1 for the model to predict both classes.

Comment: Make sense as if they affect the model, the the answer is yes. But, now I realize once we apply re-sampling we might not need to apply weighting.

Comment: If you are applying under or over sampling or some algorithm like SMOTE/ROSE then weights are not a good idea. But generally I prefer using  weights. They are easier to implement and more straightforward.

Comment: Ohh. Thanks for your time and help